JWT signature does not match locally computed signature, although the key signed-with when generating and validating token is the same
I'd googled about this problem but i still can't find an answer for myself.
I'm using Spring Boot and what I'm doing is generating a link where users can access and change password. The link, containing a jwt token, will be sent to the user's email
Here's the function that i use to do that
public ResponseEntity<String> sendChangePasswordEmail(String email, boolean isInManagement) {
    if(isExistEmail(email)) {
        log.warn("Sent email to: " + email);
        String token = jwtService.generateToken(email, 3600000); //generate token here
        String link;
        if(isInManagement) {
            link = Constants.CONTEXT_PATH + "/management/changepassword?auth=" + token;
        } else {
            link = Constants.CONTEXT_PATH + "/changepassword?auth=" + token;
        }
        return emailService.sendToUser(EmailDetailsDto.builder().recipient(email).subject("Change password").messageBody(link).build())
                ? ResponseEntity.ok().build() : ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
    }
    return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
}

Send email to user (sendToUser):
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
public boolean sendToUser(EmailDetailsDto emailDetailsDto) {
    try {
        // Creating a simple mail message
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();

        // Setting up necessary details
        mailMessage.setFrom(sender);
        mailMessage.setTo(emailDetailsDto.getRecipient());
        mailMessage.setText(emailDetailsDto.getMessageBody());
        mailMessage.setSubject(emailDetailsDto.getSubject());

        // Sending the mail
        javaMailSender.send(mailMessage);

        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("failed to send email: " + e);
        return false;
    }
}

Here's the function for generating the token
public String generateToken(String subject, long expiration) {
    Date now = new Date();
    Date expiryDate = new Date(now.getTime() + expiration);
    return Jwts.builder().setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(now)
            .setExpiration(expiryDate).signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, Constants.JWT_SECRET).compact();
}

After the user receives the email, they will click on the link, and the token will be validated by this function
public boolean validateToken(String token) {
    try {
        Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(Constants.JWT_SECRET).parseClaimsJws(token);
        return true;
    } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
        log.error("Invalid JWT token");
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
        log.error("Expired JWT token");
    } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
        log.error("Unsupported JWT token");
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        log.error("JWT token is empty");
    }
    return false;
}

The JWT signature error occurs at the line
Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(Constants.JWT_SECRET).parseClaimsJws(token);

I'd read that the different signingKeys in generation and validation will lead to this error, but in my case, they're the same and are Constants.JWT_SECRET . The time is also in milliseconds, but i still get this error. Can anyone explain why? And how can i fix this?

Start by testing if the problem is on signing or validating. Test your generated compact base64 token at https://jwt.io
I am presuming that your JWT_SECRET is a byte[]. You will need to Base64Encode in your code to get a String that works with jwt.io

EDIT:
I found out why. It was the auto translation of the email that made the token wrong. After I turned that off, it worked as normal.
